# Jquery working with Multiple Text boxes , array of text boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, textbox

I have dynamically generated text boxes and want to do calculations with their values using jquery.

The text box names are as follows :

```
A[1] , B[1]  - on change event , Alert SUM of values of A[1] and B[1]

A[2] , B[2]  - on change event , Alert SUM of values of A[2] and B[2] 

A[3] , B[3]   - on change event , Alert SUM of values of A[3] and B[3]

.
.
.
.
A[10] , B[10]   - on change event , Alert SUM of values of A[10] and B[10]
```

How to make a function in jquery for this task.
Please help me in accomplishing this task.

I have this code but its for all the text boxes A and B , but I want to specify SETS OF VALUES LIKE   SUM of A[1] and B[1] , SUM of A[2] and B[2] .......

```
$("input[type='text'][name^='A'] ,input[type='text'][name^='B']").
keyup(function(){ 

alert(sumThemUp());

});


function sumThemUp(){
var sum = 0;

$("input[type='text'][name^='A'] ,input[type='text'][name^='B']").
each(function(){

sum+= parseInt($(this).val());

});

return sum;

    };
```

My HTML is:

```
<input type="text" name="A[1]">
<input type="text" name="B[1]">
<input type="text" name="A[2]">
<input type="text" name="B[2]">
.
.
.
.
.<input type="text" name="A[10]">
<input type="text" name="B[10]">
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: I don't know what to do ? How do fetch the values of A[1] and B[1] using a function

Comment: You might want to begin by posting your code.

Comment: Give your DOM elements a class, query that class, do work with the result set. If you want it to update on blur, then use the jquery .on() method to fire off your script. I assume your results go at the end of each column and the end of each row? You need to elaborate your requirements.

Comment: i have posted some code please check it out

Answer (score 1):

I think you're trying something like this:

```
$('input[type=text]').on('keyup', function() {
    var cur = this.name;
    if(cur.indexOf('A') == 0){
       var target = 'B' + cur.replace('A','');
    } else target = 'A' + cur.replace('B','');
    var targetVal = $('input[name="'+ target +'"]').val();
    var sum = parseInt(this.value) + parseInt(targetVal ? targetVal: 0);
    console.log(sum);
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/thecodeparadox/CDnWg/5/)**

Comment: sir, i want to select the value of this textbox with name : A[1] using this selector : var id = 1; ------------------------------------------------- var a = $("input[type='text'][name='A\["+id+"\]").val(); --------------------------------------------------is my syntax correct?

Comment: use this:  `$('input[type=text][name="A['+ id +']"]')`;

Comment: yes sir i will work on it too...will tell as soon as i complete...thanks for your great help

Answer (score 1):

This is probably the simplest way to do it that I can think of. It will require a slight modification to your dynamic DOM stuff, but I assume you always generate an A and a B, so this shouldn't be a problem.

HTML:

```
<span class="calc_group">
    <input type="text" name="A[1]">
    <input type="text" name="B[1]">
</span>
<span class="calc_group">
    <input type="text" name="A[2]">
    <input type="text" name="B[2]">
</span>
```

jQuery:

NOTE: this will NEED to be called within your dynamic DOM function on every addition!

```
function doAttachment(){
     $('.calc_group input').unbind('keyup');

     $('.calc_group input').keyup(function(){
           var sum = 0;
           $(this).parent().children().each(function(){
                sum += parseInt($(this).val());
           });

           alert(sum);
      });
}
```

Comment: sir, i want to select the value of this textbox with name : A[1] using this selector : var id = 1; ------------------------------------------------- var a = $("input[type='text'][name='A\["+id+"\]").val(); --------------------------------------------------is my syntax correct?